# Extracting an element and converting it to datetime

Tags: python

I'm currently working with a bunch of lists, and I wanted to extract a certain element and set it to datetime format.

So I have a sample code below:

```
mylist = ['Bananas', 200, 500, 'Walmart', '201309', 10, 12, 44, 11, 43]

print datetime.strptime(''.join(mylist[4:5]), '%Y%m')
```

My question is, is there a better way of doing this?

My expected output is:
2013-09-01 00:00:00

Comment: Yes, my original code works. Sometimes I tend to overanalyze stuff and make simple things complicated. mylist[4] works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the single element.

```
print datetime.strptime(mylist[4], '%Y%m')
```

Comment: It is funny how I over analyze things sometimes.